# why the recent NiFi logs are getting deleted automatically from the log directory?

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi version 1.5:

recently, i have noticed that NiFi logs are getting deleted from the log directory. for example, logs are generated with nifi-app-xxxx.log with today's timestamp in hourly basis. the same log files are getting deleted if we check it day after tomorrow. this is happening for all the dates.

below is the configuration that i checked, but stuck how to proceed further:
**logback.xml**:

```
<file>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/nifi-app.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<!--
            For daily rollover, use 'app_%d.log'.
            For hourly rollover, use 'app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log'.
            To GZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.gz'.
            To ZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.zip'.
-->
<fileNamePattern>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/nifi-app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
<maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
<!-- keep 30 log files worth of history -->
<maxHistory>30</maxHistory>

<!-- optional setting for keeping 10GB total of log files
<totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
-->
</rollingPolicy>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional maxHistory property controls the maximum number of archive files to keep, asynchronously deleting older files. For example, if you specify monthly rollover, and set maxHistory to 6, then 6 months worth of archives files will be kept with files older than 6 months deleted.

Setting hourly rollover, and maxHistory=30, will keep logs for last 30 hours.

Check all the logback logger params here:

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Comment: in my configuration, since it is hourly rollover and maxHistory is 30. hence, it keeps the files only for 30hours and every hour its deleting the files older than 30 hours. is my understanding right?